# fetching data as new instance of existing class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to learn to code more OO and have been using PDO's. However, I am struggling to find examples in the documentation for several PDO functions.

I am using PDO's fetch_class function, and the following code successfully echoes each team's info as per the display() function. My question is fourfold;

1)Is a new instance of the TeamInfo class being created each time using PDO fetch_class?

2)If so - what is each one named? Or are they all created as just TeamInfo?

3)Is there a way to reference a particular instance of the class in future code? Like using the index value of an array?

4)Is there a way to declare a name for each new instance of the class as the data is fetched from the database - maybe using the value of a particular row each time (team_name for example.

The code...

```
class TeamInfo {
public $team_name;
public $aka;
public $website;
public $main_contact;
public $phone;
public $email;
public $other;

public function display() {
  $output='';
  $output.=$this->team_name;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->aka;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->website;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->main_contact;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->phone;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->email;
  $output.='<br>' . $this->other;

  return $output;

}
}

require_once "old_pdo_enl_connect.php";

$database=dbNB_connect();

$query=$database->query("SELECT team_name, aka, website, main_contact, phone, email,     other from team_directory");


foreach ($query->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'TeamInfo') as $team) {

echo $team->display() . "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) The objects are assigned to `$team` (which is overwritten by next object on each iteration)  variable and the class is `TeamInfo`

3) You can save array of objects:

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'TeamInfo');
```

And access to every row:

```
$rows[0]->team_name;
```

4) You can create associated array with `team_name` as key:

```
$rows = array()
foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'TeamInfo') as $row) {
    $rows[$row->team_name] = $row;
}

echo $rows['ExampleTeam']->website;
```

Comment: wow thank you very much - where have you learned this from exactly? Also - bit of a random question - but is my code (and the examples you have given) good OO code? Before I just used a while loop and echoed the team_name, website etc and it worked fine - I guess this is tidier which is an advantage

Comment: You're welcome. Just years of practice. You don't need to use objects and classes everywhere in your code. The idea of OO style is to make code more portable, easy to maintenance and easy to extend. Is it good OO code? If you are happy how it works, how you can use it and it is meet your expectations it must be good OO code :) It's just my thoughts.